# Recovering backup from wrong version

Tags: firebird

I have a backup file that I cannot confirm but I am 99% positive it was created using version 2.1. Now I try to recover it using version 2.1.4.18393 using this command:

```
  c:\users\me\documents> "c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\bin\gbak.exe" -C tmp.gbk "localhost:c:\users\me\documents\sgl.fdb" -v -user sysdba -password masterkey
```

and I get this error:

```
  gbak: ERROR:Expected backup version 1..8.  Found 9
```

I tried to recover using firebird 2.5 but got

```
  gbak: ERROR:Malformed string
  gbak:Invalid metadata detected. Use -FIX_FSS_METADATA option.
```

How can I recover this file?

Comment: Do you know what character set the backup was created with? In that case, you should specify it (in 2.5) when restoring.

Comment: The first error message makes it clear the backup was created using Firebird 2.5 (gbak backup format version 9 is for Firebird 2.5)

Comment: I had the same error when recovering using Flamerobin. It was also migration from 2.1 to 2.5 (actually starting from 2.0 through 2.1 and the final version is 3.0). The first message was missing, the second was there though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For example
gbak -r -v -user sysdba -pas xxx -fix_fss_metadata win1251 -fix_fss_data win1251 db.gbk db.fdb

PS win1251 is my database charset

Comment: That was it. I was a little dazzled because I never installed Firebird 2.5 on my clients and this one had id. She updated by herself. Thank you very much.

Comment: It worked well for me too: I was trying to restore from 2.1 > 2.5 version and gbak told me to use  -fix_fss_metadata.